# What would be the optimal schema for this relationship?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

Basically a worker reads a queue of rows. I create a table called `Work` . A worker takes a row (work), it contains several tasks. Each task has several properties.

Is this essentially a `Work` table with has_many relationship to a `Task` table holding all the individual tasks belong into a specific `work_id`? And the individual properties belonging to a single task would be just columns?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in my opinion(like yours), **Work** and **Task** should be separate tables, where the relation would be, a **Work** has_many **Task**

```
class Work(Model):
    workname = TextField()

class Task(Model):
    work = ForeignKeyField(Work, related_name='works')
    taskname = TextField()
```